# How is this memory handled?

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management

I have a very simple questions about the way memory is managed.

```
aObject * object = [[aObject alloc] init];
NSArray * array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:object, nil];
```

Does the array just hold the location of memory to `Object` or is memory allocated again for the size of `object` when it is added to the array?

Also if I had `object` already allocated but I were to hold a reference to that `object` in a different file, does the reference allocate memory of its own or does it just hold the location to the original memory? for example:

```
@implementation aFile {
    aObject * object;
}
-(void)blah{
    object = [Aobject alloc] init];
}
@end


@implementation anotherFile {
    aObject * objectRef;
}
-(void)setObjectRef:(aObject*)object{
    objectRef = object;
}
@end
```

if i were to call `setObjectRef:` and pass in the `object` created in `aFile`, is memory allocated again for `objectRef` or is it just a reference to the original memory of `object`?

Comment: FYI the object you defined in setObjectRef is not same as you declared in aFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an NSArray with objects, it is really a *pointer* to the **array of pointers**. What it means is that when you pass the object, the object ***isn't*** allocated again, in fact it **keeps the reference** to the object. It means, if you pass mutable object to the array (like NSMutableString etc.), then you append something to the string, the array will change its value. If you, on the other hand, initialize the object again, with different value, the memory address changes for that object, but array keeps the reference to the old object - it means there are 2 different objects. Better to see it on examples:

**Example 1:**

```
NSString *testString = @"Test";
NSArray *testArray = @[testString];

testString = @"Test2";
```

Here we create immutable object and pass it to the array. Lets say testString has address 0x1, testArray 0x99. When we pass literal to the testString, its nothing more than alloc and then init with that string. What it means is it **will reallocate the memory** and then the address will be different, e.g. 0x2. The array still has the reference to 0x1. *2 different objects*.

**Example 2:**

```
NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Test"];
NSArray *testArray = @[testString];

[testString appendString:@"2"];
```

Here we create mutable object. Lets say it has address 0x1, array address 0x2. When we append the string, **the address doesn't change**. Why? Because when creating mutable string compiler suspects you will change the size of it, so it allocates more than you need for that specific moment. Appending something won't change it address. When we change the testString, we also change the value of the string in the array. *1 object instead of 2 different*.

**Example 3:**

```
NSMutableString *testString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Test"];
NSArray *testArray = @[testString];

testString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Test2"];
```

Here we have mutable object passed to the array. Again lets say it is 0x1, array 0x2. What is the different here? We don't actually change the string, we **reallocate** the memory by passing literal, even tho it is mutable string. What it means is that when passing the literal, **the memory address changed** for 0x3, but array still keeps 0x1.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C objects are only allocated by very specific methods, usually only `copy`, `new` and `alloc`, almost everything else uses references to objects.

`NSArray` simply stores pointers to the objects, the values are not copied.

`aObject* object;` declares a pointer to an object. Pointers do not copy the object they point to when assigned. Instead, assigning them changes the address they point to.

In your `setObjectRef` method the pointer is just being assigned so nothing is being copied.

Comment: Small nitpick, it's actually only `allocWithZone:` that does memory allocation and is invoked by `alloc`. `copy` and `copyWithZone:` call these two methods to allocate memory.

Comment: @JustSid I was referring more to the naming of those method for usability, not where allocation actually happens. If you see some kind of alloc or copy call you have good reason to assume memory allocation.